# Prerequisites for QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to learn QR decomposition method and algorithm, I wonder what the prerequisites are that matix $A$ must fulfill other than being a square matrix. Could the method be applied on any square matrix?

Comment: you do not need to have a square matrix to do QR.  If A is an $m\times{n}$, and $rank(A)=n$, then A can be expressed as $QR$ where $Q$ is an $m\times{n}$ matrix and $R$ is a $n\times{n}$ matrix.

Comment: As mentioned above, the rank must be $n$.  I.e., your columns must be linearly independent, det$(A)\neq{0}$, etc.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst: So $A$ must be non-singular, right?

Comment: yes.  That's all you need.  I mean, you neeed to have a defined inner product as well as you have to Gram-Schmidt A to get Q...